# Stop jquery-ui datepicker from showing in beforeShow

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I wish to do something like this:

```
var showme = false;

$('#mydatepicker').datepicker({
    beforeShow: function(input, inst) {
        if(!showme) {
            //stop showing
        }
    }
});
```

But disable, nor hide seems to work. I'd like to do something that works like preventDefault, but I don't think it'll work in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking through the source, it doesn't look like that is possible currently. You might be able to request that as a feature. If you really want to make it stop (though this is probably a bad idea) you could throw an error in that function. Though this will cause errors to show up for your page and probably is not an option.

---

**Note**: I submitted a patch for this and it's now in the released jQuery UI (at *least* v1.9 and later), although the documentation doesn't mention it. `return false` in `beforeShow` will prevent the datepicker from appearing (now).

Comment: Thanks @joekarl I might suggest it to the ui team. Interesting idea abotu throwing an error... it's quite funny I thought I managed to find a solution earlier, but it was because of my dody code I threw an error by mistake :-)

Comment: I actually just made a patch for this, sent a pull request on github but I doubt it will go through any time soon....

Comment: Has been merged into the master, not sure when the next stable release is. commit d1462973

Answer (score 7):

I had the same question, and have discovered that you can now use `return false;` to prevent the calendar from showing.

```
$('#mydatepicker').datepicker({
    beforeShow: function(input, inst) {
        if(!showme) {
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

I'm using version 1.7.2 of jQuery UI

Comment: Cool, which version of jquery / jquery-ui are you using, for future reference?

Answer (score 1):

It might be better to simply control the showing of the datepicker with the *disable* and *enable* method parameters.

```
$('#mydatepicker').datepicker('disable'); //Don't show datepicker 

$('#mydatepicker').datepicker('enable'); //Show datepicker
```

It would seem to accomplish the same purpose that you are seeking.

Comment: Thanks @Adam Prax good suggestion, but unfortunately it doesn't work inside beforeShow. I want to do some validation just before it shows. I almost need a beforeBeforeShow event :-)

Comment: I used this solution.  However, it requires doing the checks OUTSIDE the beforeShow function.  Alex, if you can do the same checks outside this method it may work for you.  In my case it was making sure a checkbox was checked before I allowed a datepicker to be used.  It was fairly straight forward after that point to use 'enable' and 'disable' to prevent the picker from displaying.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to prevent datepicker from opening is to use the following function in beforeShow:

`$("#datepicker").datepicker("close");`

this forces datepicker to close before it even get's shown.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be the closest I could get too, but I don't really want to have to use setTimeout here, it seems a bit hacky:

```
        var showme = false;

        $('#mydatepicker').datepicker({
            beforeShow: function (input, inst) {

                if (!showme) {

                    setTimeout(function () { $(input).datepicker("hide"); }, 1);

                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Since this patch has not been merged in, I was able to come up with a hack that works pretty well.  Let me know what you think:

```
beforeShow: function(){
    var start = $('#dtFrom').val()
    if($.trim(start)!=''){
        start = $('#dtFrom').datepicker('getDate');
        $('#DateToDisplay').datepicker('option', 'minDate', new Date(start.getTime()));
    }
},
    onClose: function() {
    var start = $('#dtFrom').val()
    if($.trim(start)==''){
        alert('Error! Please select a start date\/time prior to setting the date to display.');
        $('#DateToDisplay').val('')
    }
}
```