# How to conditionally prevent jQueryUi datepicker Dialog from opening?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, knockout.js

I have a jQueryUi datepicker that sometimes I do not want it to display the date picking dialog.  My question is, can I in the beforeShow option, do something that will prevent the dialog from opening?

```
  $('.date').each(function () {
       $(this).datepicker({
             beforeShow: function (input, inst) {
                 // ????  What can I put here
                 // to prevent datepicker dialog from opening? ????
                }
        });
   });
```

### edit

The reason I want to do this, is that I'm having problems with events in my application in IE8.  What is happeaning is that after user has picked a date and the input field is updated, there is another focus event is fired, which causes the datepicker dialog to re-open.  But again, only in IE8.  The problem is related to how I'm using [knockoutjs](http://knockoutjs.com/).  But finding the exact cause is proving to be very difficult.  So, if I can prevent the datepicker dialog from re-opening, it will make the problem go away from the users point of view.  Yes I know this is a bit of a hack, but it is considerably simpler than trying trace which events are firing and when.

Answer (score 0):

It appears similar to [Stop jquery-ui datepicker from showing in beforeShow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6599009/stop-jquery-ui-datepicker-from-showing-in-beforeshow). And it seems, that current jQueryUI doesn't support canceling of the opening in beforeShow. Anyway, you should really do something about that focus part, not the datepicker. Maybe you could set some variable after the first opening and then check it with focus() event on that element. Either way this will be a hack. It's best, if it's really related to knockout.js, contact the developer or fill a bug report.

Comment: I know where the problem is and it is not with knockoutjs.  It is more complicated and I was looking to see if there was an "easy" way to fix the problem.  Eventually, I found the real problem and fixed it, but it was a lot of work.