# beforeShow does not work with jquery inline datepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am trying to perform some operation before jquery datepicker is displayed.

It works fine when datepicker is attached to an input field but as soon as datepicker becomes inline then the event does not work.

I was not able to find anything while searching over google.

Any help will be appreciated.

```js
$(function(){
  
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
  beforeShow: test
});

$( ".demoInline" ).datepicker({
  inline: true,
  beforeShow: test
});

});

function test(){
 alert(1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/themes/mint-choc/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="demo">

<p>Date: <input id="datepicker" type="text"></p>

</div><!-- End demo -->
<br/><br/><br/>
Inline:
<div class="demoInline"></div><!-- End demo -->
```

http://jsfiddle.net/0wsyzuem/1/

Thanks...

Comment: https://forum.jquery.com/topic/datepicker-beforeshow and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6599009/stop-jquery-ui-datepicker-from-showing-in-beforeshow   it doesn't look like that is possible currently

Comment: these links does not refer to inline datepicker and for datepicker attached to input I am able to call beforeShow and I am not trying to stop the calendar show.

Comment: This is your answer - http://stackoverflow.com/a/12286320/962734

Comment: Artur, Atleast I m not able to make it run http://jsfiddle.net/gduhm/130/

Comment: It does work. There was a syntax error "`Unexpected token }`" in your code - http://jsfiddle.net/gduhm/131/